# Textinput with variable Placeholder and clear on buttonclick

Tags: react-native

im a little stuck here in want to have a textinput with the last value commited set as placeholder

and a button, which

- sets the text to the placeholder variable
- clears the textinput text
- and gives the text from the input to some other function

my code so far:

```
export default class FirstScreen extends Component{
  state = {
  'Username': ''
}   
componentDidMount = () => AsyncStorage.getItem('Username').then((value) => 
this.setState({ 'Username': value }))

setUsername = (value) => {
 AsyncStorage.setItem('Username', value);
 this.setState({ 'Username': value });
}


// initialize empty text for textinputs
 constructor(props) {
 super(props);
   this.state = {text: '',text2: ''};
 }

  render(){
    return(



 {/*some ohther code*/}



  <TextInput
      placeholder= {this.state.Username}
      onChangeText={(value) => this.setState({text: value})}
      //onFocus={({text}) => this.setUsername(text)}
      value={this.state.text}
      style={{ width: 200, height: 44, padding: 8 }}
    />

      <Button
        title={"Login"}
        onPress={this.clearAndLogin}
        color="rgb(0, 38, 100)"
       />




clearAndLogin= () => {
  this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
  {/*I gave up on other code here because nothing worked*/}
};
```

### edit 07.06.2018 16:39

thanks to [Shubhanu Sharma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7012018/shubhanu-sharma) the problem ist mostly done but dtere is a little kink left

#### behaviour at the moment:

(values are simplyfied for best possible understanding)

1. App starts

   Values:

   ```
    Asyncstorage-value: "user1"
    Placeholder-value: "user1" (Placeholder loaded correctly from AS)
    Usertextinput-value: ""
   ```
2. User2 is typing its credentials

   Values:

   ```
    Asyncstorage-Value: "user1"
    Placeholder-value: "user1"
    Usertextinput: "user2"
   ```
3. User2 clicks loginbutton

   Values:

   ```
    Asyncstorage-Value: "user2"
    Placeholder-value: "user1"
    Usertextinput: ""
   ```
4. User2 uses app .... and after that user2 loggs out and shows login-screen again

   Values:

   ```
    Asyncstorage-Value: "user2"
    Placeholder-value: "user1" (here ist the mistake, should be "user2")
    Usertextinput: ""
   ```

(if I would restart the whole app it would load the correct placeholder but not if i am just sining out (navigate to that screen))

#### desired behaviour

1. App starts

   Values:

   ```
    Asyncstorage-value: "user1"
    Placeholder-value: "user1" (Placeholder loaded correctly from AS)
    Usertextinput-value: ""
   ```
2. User2 is typing its credentials

   Values:

   ```
    Asyncstorage-Value: "user1"
    Placeholder-value: "user1"
    Usertextinput: "user2"
   ```
3. User2 clicks loginbutton

   Values:

   ```
    Asyncstorage-Value: "user2"
    Placeholder-value: "user2"
    Usertextinput: ""
   ```
4. User2 uses app .... and after that user2 loggs out and shows login-screen again

   Values:

   ```
    Asyncstorage-Value: "user2"
    Placeholder-value: "user2" (!!!!)
    Usertextinput: ""
   ```

i hope its now more understandable thanks for all!!

Comment: I am unable to understand can you please eleborate.

Comment: what do you not understand?

Comment: Initially you will get and value from async storage and put as placeholder value and then user will enter some value in textField then that value you want somewhere and onPress of login button click you want to clear textField right ???

Comment: exactly! and save the text wich the user has typed in to asyncstorage for the next time the screen opens

Comment: oh o got it. so after logging out what are you doing navigation.pop() ???

Comment: right now my singout-process is  as simple as the "login" so my "signout" Code is:   _signOutAsync = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Login');
  };

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is working for me.

My assumption is you will call an api that will give you response with success or unauthorised according to that we will set value in storage.

I have given example using axios u can use anything or some other logic.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Button,
  TextInput,
  AsyncStorage
} from "react-native";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { placeholder: "", Username: "" };
  }

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    const lastName = await AsyncStorage.getItem("Username");
    if (lastName) {
      this.setState({ placeholder: lastName });
    }
  };

  setUsername = value => {
    AsyncStorage.setItem("Username", value);
    this.setState({ Username: value });
  };
  // initialize empty text for textinputs
  clearAndLogin = () => {
    axios
      .get("url", { params: { username: this.state.username, password: "" } })
      .then(res => {
        if (res.code === 200) {
          AsyncStorage.setItem("Username", this.state.Username);
          this.setState(
            {
              Username: ""
            },
            () => {
              // change route
            }
          );
        } else {
          alert("unauthorized user");
        }
      });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TextInput
          placeholder={this.state.placeholder || "first time user"}
          onChangeText={Username => this.setState({ Username })}
          value={this.state.Username}
          style={{ width: 200, height: 44, padding: 8 }}
        />
        <Button
          title={"Login"}
          onPress={this.clearAndLogin}
          color="rgb(0, 38, 100)"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: at first THANKS for the great effort! It works like a charm besides one little kink. if i logout an go back to the login page without restrating the whole app its still the old Placeholder-value

Comment: If you want to remove on logout then that time you have to remove this value from async storage.

Comment: no i dont want to remove it. i want it to refresh the value of the placeholder so it shows the value of the real last login and not the last login since the app has been started

Comment: yes regardless of whether the app is fresh started or navigated back with logout

Comment: for authentication are you calling some backend api ??

Comment: at the moment it has no logic implemented (right now its just "this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');" to go to the main page)

Comment: well thanks for the axios code but that doesnt touch my problem. i try to explan it short 1.fresh loaded App (placeholder shows "user1"(because he was logged in befor the app was closed)) 2. user2 loggs in, then is doing something and finaly logs out 3. now back at the loginscreen (placeholder shows still "user1" but should show "user2" due he ist the last logged in user)  so the problem is placeholder stick to the same value until the whole app is closed and started again

Comment: So if user will logout then we have to remove current user name and get back last user (who logged in before this user) name always. Like that ?

Comment: see edit i tried to explain it as precisely as possible